# Combine 2 SQL queris into 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these 2 SQL queries. I want to combine into 1. For now the first query gives me a list of users and what shipable items they have while the user doesnt. The 2nd query tells what items the user have and the other doesnt have as shipable.

SQL1:

```
SELECT max(t1.username) AS 'Username',
group_concat(t2.item_no ORDER BY t2.id ASC separator ', ') AS 'Item List'
FROM table3 t3
INNER JOIN accounts t1 ON t3.user_id = t1.id
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.item_id = t2.id
INNER JOIN (
SELECT t3.*
FROM table3 t3
WHERE t3.user_id = 17 and t3.stat = 0
AS c ON t3.item_id = c.item_id 
WHERE t3.shipped = 1 AND t3.user_id != 17
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY COUNT('Item List') DESC;
```

SQL2:

```
SELECT max(t1.username) AS 'Username',
            group_concat(t2.item_no ORDER BY t2.id ASC separator ', ') AS 'MY Item List'
            FROM table3 t3
            INNER JOIN accounts t1 ON t3.user_id = t1.id
            INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.item_id = t2.id
             INNER JOIN (
              SELECT t3.*
              FROM table3 t3
              WHERE t3.user_id = 17 and t3.shipped = 1
            ) AS d ON t3.item_id = d.item_id
            WHERE t3.stat = 0 AND t3.user_id != 17
            GROUP BY t1.id
            ORDER BY COUNT('MY Item List') DESC;
```

I think the answer is in the middle part, but i cannot fit this code to the other one:

```
INNER JOIN (
              SELECT t3.*
              FROM table3 t3
              WHERE t3.user_id = 17 and t3.shipped = 1
            ) AS d ON t3.item_id = d.item_id
```

I want a result something like this:

| USERNAME | MY ITEM LIST | ITEM LIST |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 1, 2 | 5, 6 |
| John | 3, 4 | 5, 7 |

Table Structures:

Table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_no varchar(255),
    item_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 3

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  stat tinyint NOT NULL,
  shipped tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a sample of your input tables as well?

Comment: table3 looks like this: https://pastebin.com/XNCAEGtp

Comment: can you provide some more information about your tables? column "item_id" on table3 is the primary key? and what is the reason you join using a sub-query instead of normal join?

Comment: i added the structures of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this query:

```
SELECT 
  max(t1.username) AS 'Username',
  group_concat(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t3_2.user_id = 17 THEN t2.item_no END ORDER BY t2.id ASC separator ', ') AS 'MY Item List',
  group_concat(DISTINCT CASE WHEN t3_1.user_id != 17 THEN t2.item_no END ORDER BY t2.id ASC separator ', ') AS 'Item List'
FROM 
  table3 t3_1
INNER JOIN 
  accounts t1 
    ON t3_1.user_id = t1.id
INNER JOIN 
  table2 t2 
    ON t3_1.item_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN 
  table3 t3_2 
    ON  t3_2.item_id = t3_1.item_id 
    AND t3_2.user_id = 17 
    AND t3_2.shipped = 1
WHERE 
  t3_1.shipped = 1 
  AND t3_1.user_id != 17 
  AND t3_1.stat = 0
GROUP BY 
  t1.id
ORDER BY 
  COUNT(DISTINCT t2.item_no) DESC;
```

Comment: Looks good so far Thank you! One more little thing: How can I list out the user=17 AND shipped=1 BUT user!=17 AND stat=0 in the My Item list column?

Comment: You can use OR operator in a WHERE part. Something like:

WHERE
        (user = 17 AND shipped = 1) 
  OR (user != 17 AND stat = 0)